Update a particular repeating section entry on a form
I have a repeating section on a Cognito form. I need to be able to update a particular repeating section entry using power automate.
In power automate, I can add data sequentially, but all entries seem to need re-populating and if I try to write just one entry, it removes all but a new first section.
Surely there must be a way of updating field x in section y without overwriting all the fields in all sections?
I do not really want to have to get entry data and re-commit it in some loop, dripping in the new data…
Driving me around the bend…..
Maybe somebody has a suggestion?
